# Delete return in a text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text-files, clipboard

I did a batch file to help my friends to create virtual drive. The script use subst function.

I was looking for a solution to copy what was in the clipboard to put in my string `subst x: "clipboard"` (Because I told them to copy the path in Windows explorer that they want to have a virtual drive)

I found a string that can copy the clipboard to a text file : `powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()" >textfile.txt` (because I didn't found a way to get the answer directly in a variable)

Now, my problem is that, when it very long path, the textfile have return that separate the path so I'm not able, to get all the path when I read the text file because they have more that one line.

My question is : How to do to edit the text file to erase the return OR how to get they information return by my string powershell directly in a variable ?

Here was my original post :

When I do

```
powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()" >textfile.txt
```

I have a nice text file but they put return at the end of each line. What I copy from clipboard is path from the explorer, example:

```
G:\UO1111\600-00 FONCTIONS POLICIERES\200-000000-001\ BEQUILLE\Numerisation\Surveillances physiques\2000-00-00  annexe 112
```

But in the text file it do:

```
G:\UO1111\600-00 FONCTIONS POLICIERES\295-050301-001\BEQUILLE\Numerisation\Surv
eillances physiques\2005-04-20  annexe 112
```

Like you can see after Surv, it does a return.

What I try to do is to erase the return to get all the path in one line when I read the text file.

(Sometime I can have 3 or 4 lines long for the path)

Comment: What does this have to do with *batch-file*? (Powershell is not Windows batch; it's Powershell.) How are you viewing the text file to see it with a *return*? If it's in Notepad, have you turned off word-wrap to make sure it's an actual return? How do you *read the text file*?

Comment: I can't replicate your output using that file path. It outputs all on one line for me.

Comment: Well, is to create virtual drive because my path are too long (more that 256 car.) so when I'm using subst, the path are shorten so I can open the folder. I did a batch file to help friends that don't know how to do it. So i'm using powershell to get the path from the clipboard and after, I want to use it in a string `subst x: "%path%"` the path come from the powershell command that I'm sending in a text file

Comment: `[windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText().Replace([Environment]::NewLine,[string]::Empty)`

Comment: @BaconBits I took your string but I have an error, missing property after operator. Here my string `powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText().Replace([Environment]::‌​NewLine,[string]::Em‌​pty)" >textfile.txt`